# Can a async method be run asynchronously from synchronous code

Tags: c#, asynchronous, synchronous

Is it possible to call into an **async** method so that it runs asynchronously from a method that is synchronous? I'm not concerned with it hanging the synchronous caller until it returns, but want the method to be called asynchronously.

I am not asking if synchronous code can call an **async** method in general. I know that it can, but it will run the **async** method synchronously (as well as every **async** method called inside it), which is the situation I'm trying to avoid.

To give more details:

an instance of an interface is created using **Activator.CreateInstance**. This interface has a couple public **async** methods. One implementation of this interface launches a GUI so a tester can manually specify the return value of the method. It works fine if it is called asynchronously. However, if it is not called asynchronously, the GUI freezes. I believe this is happening because the asynchronous functionality behind the GUI no longer works.

I have some code that calls the method that is run synchronously. Is it possible to call the method so that its internal calls run asynchronously from this code? I've tried creating a second thread to call the **async** method (perhaps incorrectly) and still had the GUI freeze up. The reason I believe not running asynchronously is the key issue is if I change code that *is* running asynchronously to call the method without using **await** it exhibits the same issue as if I called it from the synchronously run code.

Comment: This bit is wrong: "I am not asking if synchronous code can call an async method in general. I know that it can, but it will run the async method synchronously (as well as every async method called inside it), which is the situation I'm trying to avoid." If you just call an async method, it WILL run asynchronously (provided it was implemented correctly).

Comment: Thought I read that on MSDN, but can't find it now. Would the question be better worded "can I call an async method with await from a method that isn't marked async"?

Comment: that's what happens when you use `await` to wait from the synchronous method to wait for the `async` method to finish.

Answer (score 2):

In order for your user interface window to show and operate it needs the thread that is creating the window to process windows messages. Without a message loop spinning the window will freeze and refuse to operate.

So your main thread (which is the applications user interface thread) is calling your interface method that then wants to show a window. If the calling method does not return until the interface method is completed then it will freeze, the message loop cannot spin until your method returns.

Your only solution is to have the interface implementation use a separate thread for showing the window and that other thread will need its own message loop that allows the window to operate.

Having multiple user interface threads is not very common but it can be done.

Answer (score 1):

**Return void, and trigger an event**

**async** methods can be declared as returning **void**. This will allow code that is unaware of the **Task** class to call it. Though you can't return the result directly from the method itself, you can trigger an event when a result is ready. Just add an event handler to your code that is calling the method and you can get the results when available.

I had originally overlooked this as I'm going from VB6 to C#. But it turns out it is [relatively easy to implement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/murat/archive/2008/11/20/exposing-com-events-c.aspx) this. If for some reason events are out of the picture, you could probably poll a a results property on the object owning the **async** method until it is set.

Comment: This is just making the method be asynchronous, and simply using an event-based asynchronous model instead of a `Task` based asynchronous model.  One could also have a callback based asynchronous model, among other possible ways of making an operation asynchronous.